# code error- Real Time Clock program-DS3231 RTC module

Tags: compile

I'am a NEW-B with an ELEGOO mega 2560 starter kit.The program code came from their disc.The verifying error message for the declaration: RTCDateTime dt; is

RTCDateTime' does mot name a type

exit status 1

'RTCDateTime'does not name a type

I can not determine what this means or how to correct.
HELP,Dick

Comment: I downloaded the tutorial code for ELEGOO Mega Most Complete Starter Kit from here: http://www.elegoo.com/tutorial/ (their web site is a mess of broken links). The RTC example (Lesson 19) does indeed use `RTCDateTime` type. However, the accompanying `DS3231` library does properly define that type in `DS3231.h`. So, in that package the problem you are reporting does not exist. Maybe the version on the disc has some kind of typo? And your sure you are using *their* libraries?

Comment: My bet would be that you simply included a third-party `DS3231.h`, which has nothing to do with the proper `DS3231.h`. Hence the error.